# Maven web module not running from inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have configure Maven Multimodule project and when i am doing

```
mvn clean install
```

It is Creating War and Jar files for both the modules in the parent project and when i am deploying war file in Tomcat6 it is working fine.

But when i am trying to run the web module from inside eclipse .

> Right Click on project->Run on Server ->Selected Tomcat as a Server

Then Project not working .

The Web Module is depended on the java project which is also a part of **Multimodule** project so i added dependency of this(Java) project into my web project but in web project Java build path not containing this dependency .Can anyone know how can i resolve this issue with eclipse?
As i saw in eclipse's

workspace_maven.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\web\WEB-INF\lib

i did not found the Java project here .But when i am doing

```
mvn clean install
```

and deploying that war in Tomcat the **/WEB-INF/lib**  directory containing my Java Project jar file.
 My Web Module Pom.xml file...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo_parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.csdc</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name> web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>  


    <build>
        <finalName>amanda-web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my parent pom.xml file...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo_parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>

        <module>demo-web</module>
        <module>core-java</module>
    </modules>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration> 
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Note:-**I have removed repository and dependency from parent pom.xml to make pom short.

Comment: Have you installed the m2e-wtp plugin?

Comment: yes i installed it from eclipse market place

Comment: Which error do you get when you run it from eclipse?

Comment: When i am running application in tomcat server from inside ecipse come classes which needed when project starting and part of java project not available so it is telling class not found exception

Comment: Can you also post the parent POM?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19570/discussion-between-mickael-marrache-and-subodh)

Comment: Hi Mickael Can you send me some demo example? As your environment have no any such issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should need the [apache maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)

The goal should be like `tomcat:run`

It will download the new instance of tomcat in your target folder and deploy your war on that tomcat.

You can set all the setting for that tomcat or can refer the setting XML in the `configuration` tag of the plugin.

You can run it as debug mode and all the changes can be seen on the fly. (Java, JSP files only. no XML and properties)

for your help I am adding a code that would help you in running the tomcat server and deploy the WAR when you install the web module.

The application will be installed in tomcat 5 and on the root context.
You can access it on URL: `http://localhost:8080/`

```
<project>
...
<build>
  <finalName>myWAR</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>RUN_TOMCAT</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: It would be needed in Parent Pom.xml or web module Pom.xml? And My web Module is running in Tomcat but due to Java Project Dependency it is not working

Comment: you need to add it in the web module. WAR plugin also include all the dependent and parent jars so no need to configure anything for that.

Comment: I have added web module pom.xml file Please have a look and let me know it is right or not

Comment: I made change in web pom.xml file but still i am getting same issue project not working from inside eclipse, As i already mentioned that eclipse showing me run project on server and it is deploying but web project need some of the claases of Java project to start so on running tomcat from eclipse showing Some class not found exception on server startup

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan I don't think the Maven Tomcat plugin is mandatory. I deploy web applications from Eclipse+M2E without this plugin and it works perfectly.