# maven multi module project repeated build issue

Tags: maven, compiler-construction, build, build-process

I have created a multi module maven project as below

```
 - root module(parent module. Building this will build the below children modules)

      dao

      service

      web
```

**dao** and **service** modules creates the jar file. **web** module creates the final war file to be deployed. **service** module has the dependency of **dao** module. **web** module has the dependency of **service** module.

Whenever I implement new functionality, I have to modify all the modules from **dao** to **web**. I have a **maven jetty plugin configured in web module**. To test any new implemented functionality in UI I end up building **dao** and **service** modules always. Are there anyway to avoid this process and reflect the changes from **dao** and **service** modules whenever I run **mvn jetty:run** in web module?

Comment: You could have a look at JRebel, it allows you to reflect your changes without manually recompiling all the time. But it costs money and their sales guys can be really annoying.

Comment: Where do you mvn jetty:run from? I assume from the "web" module? If yes, I doubt it will recompile the dao and service modules.

Comment: Hey Dinesh..nice you too see you here man..long time ;-)

Comment: @Omnipotent :-)...Yeah. I am missing u and our Warrior. Nice to catch you back here.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to da that, and this is the intended behavior.

If you have these 3 projects, this means the have **their own lifecycle**. If not, the best is to have only one project.

However, you could avoid mentioning a version number in the project, and rely on a parent version number (your root module could also be the parent).
So, you could rebuild everything from the multi-module project.

However, I don't really see the point.

Why do you have 3 projects ?

Comment: Having multiple modules gives more flexibility. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675821/is-there-any-benefit-in-using-maven-multimodule-when-working-in-a-small-applicat. In nearer future I am going to add another module for exposing web services. So having only one module would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Ok, I see, I think you will end up with something more complex to maintain, but you can do what I proposed (eventually combined with the use of SNAPSHOT) to be able to ensure everything is rebuilt everytime you need it.